# How does Gson serialize and deserialize inherited POJOs generated by Lombok?

Tags: java, spring, gson, lombok

How do I use Java inheritance with `lombok` with `final` (immutable data type) and with `Gson` ?

```java
@ToString
@Getter
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
public abstract class AbstractContext {
  protected final String applicationUuid;
  protected final String userUuid;
  protected final String accountUuid;

  public AbstractContext(
      String applicationUuid, String userUuid, String accountUuid) {
    this.applicationUuid = applicationUuid;
    this.accountUuid = accountUuid;
    this.userUuid = userUuid;
  }
```

```java
@ToString
@Getter
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class ChildContext extends AbstractContext {
  private final String foobar;

  public ChildContext(
      String applicationUuid, String userUuid, String accountUuid, String foobar) {
    super(applicationUuid, userUuid, accountUuid);
    this.foobar = foobar;
  }
}
```

```java
Gson gson = new Gson();
ChildContext inputB =
        gson.fromJson(
            "{\"application_uuid\":\"deadbeef\",\"user_uuid\":\"aaabbb_4958\",\"foobar\":\"abc\"}",
            ChildContext.class);
```

However, the result I got is this with other parent class fields null

```
foobar=abc, application_uuid=null, user_uuid=null, account_uuid=null
```

I tried to look into using [SuperBuilder](https://www.baeldung.com/lombok-builder-inheritance) from `lombok`, but still the same result

Comment: Why do you believe that JSON field `application_uuid` would map to Java field `applicationUuid`? They are different names.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to specify the Field Naming Policy.

```java
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES)
        .create();
ChildContext inputB =
        gson.fromJson(
            "{\"application_uuid\":\"deadbeef\",\"user_uuid\":\"aaabbb_4958\",\"foobar\":\"abc\"}",
            ChildContext.class);
```